# Migrating Service reference to Channel Factory

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, proxy

I am migrating a service reference to use a channel factory.

I split the interface from the service implementation into a separate class library.

- Class Lib: `IService`
- Class Lib: `Service`
- Web Application: Reference to `IService`

Code:

**Config**

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingEndpoint" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**Class:**

```
public class ProxyManager
{
        internal static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChannelFactory<IService>> proxies = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChannelFactory<IService>>();

        internal static ChannelFactory<IService> CreateChannelFactory()
        {
            Global.Logger.Info("ProxyManager:CreateChannelFactory");
            BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;            
            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://domain/Service.svc");
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
            channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            return channelFactory;
        }

        internal static IService GetProxy(string key)
         {
             Global.Logger.Info("ProxyManager:GetProxy");
             return proxies.GetOrAdd(key, m => CreateChannelFactory()).CreateChannel();
         }

        internal static bool RemoveProxy(string key)
        {
            Global.Logger.Info("ProxyManager:RemoveProxy");
            ChannelFactory<IService> proxy;
            return proxies.TryRemove(key, out proxy);
        }
}
```

**Global:**

```
public static IService ServiceProxy
{
            get
            {
                return ProxyManager.GetProxy("Service");
            }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ServiceProxy.Method();
```

**Error:**

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your config, you'll see that you've defined `basicHttpBinding` with a security mode of `TransportCredentialOnly`.

However, when you create your `basicHttpBinding` in code, you're not specifying that security mode (and the default value is `BasicHttpSecurityMode.None`). I think you need to change your construction call to:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = 
   new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
```

Then you should have the same settings as in your config